# Javascript stop code execution and redirect if user clicks no on popup

Tags: php, javascript, html

So lets say i have a block of php code and i have an alert in one if statement saying "Only continue if blahh blahh" and they click no (or the cross) can you make it stop executing code so it doesnt happen?

Im basically doing this (facebook authentication):

```
      <?php
              } else {
      // If user does not have an account create new
            //  ----- popup would be here ---------
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['fb_id']= $fb_id;  

    if($gender == "male"){
        $gender = "1";
    } else {
        $gender = "0";
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (full_name, gender, fb_id)
        VALUES ('$full_name','$gender','$fb_id')");
    ?>
```

I hope this makes sense ;) thanks for reading :-)

Comment: You might want to do research about client side and server side code. This PHP will execute and be sent to the browser before the user has any chance of interacting with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a confirm dialogue in javascript. Check out the w3c page on it at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: Can that be called without the use of a button, kinda like an alert doesnt need a button? Thanks for that though! Certainly looks promising!

Comment: Yeah, confirm can be called from script whenever the script is run. You could run it on page load for example. Very similar to an alert.

Comment: sorry to be a noob, done a quick google and cant see how to do so, i dont want it on page load, just if it goes inside the "else" statement, is this still possible?

Comment: @IanGarratt - Sorry, I am not very familiar with php and can only provide a javascript suggestion.